# Нужно ли закрывать и открывать сокет для многоразового ввода / вывода в потом клиента?

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, tcp

я пытаюсь сделать мультиплеерную игру, используя сокеты java. Когда я пытаюсь создать ObjectOutputStream из объекта client.getOutputStream() дважды (т.е на второй итерации цикла), я сталкиваюсь с ошибкой

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2940)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3435)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:983)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:414)
    at server.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:20)
    at server.Server.run(Server.java:27)
```

Должен ли я закрывать и заного подкючаться к сокету перед повторной отправкой данных клиентам / получением данных от них?
Код потока для работы с клиентом:

```
public void run(Socket client) throws IOException {

    client.setSoTimeout(100000);
    while (true) {
                if (client.isConnected() && !client.isClosed()) {
                    try {
                        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); // Ошибка возникает здесь
                        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                        ServerRequest sr = (ServerRequest) ois.readObject();
                        else if(sr.requestType == 1) {
                            ServerResponse serverResponse = new ServerResponse(1, false, null, "Not found");
                            if (this.lobby != null) {
                                this.lobby.players--;
                                System.out.println(this.lobby.name + ": " + this.lobby.players + " players");
                            }
                            for (Lobby lobby : Server.lobbies) {
                                if (lobby.uuid.equals(sr.lobbyUUID)) {
                                    if (lobby.players < lobby.maxPlayers) {
                                        serverResponse = new ServerResponse(1, true, lobby, "Successful");
                                        lobby.players += 1;
                                        lobby.playerThreads.add(this);
                                        this.lobby = lobby;
                                    } else
                                        serverResponse = new ServerResponse(1, false, lobby, "Max player limit");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            out.writeObject(serverResponse);
                            client.getOutputStream().flush();
                        }

                   } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        try {
                            client.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("Class not found: " + e.getMessage());
                        try {
                            client.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Disconnected");
                    client.close();
                    return;
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалась весьма глупой: клиент прерывал подключение к серверу из-за ошибки, из-за этого вызывалось исключение.